# Read N number of random lines from a text file / Python

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I'm currently reading from a "collection" file which holds all possible outcomes, of type int, which I read into a DataFrame.

```
cycle = 19380816
pull = 10000000
sample = rand.sample(range(cycle),cycle-pull)
new_df = pd.read_csv('collection.txt', skiprows = sample, sep = " ", names = ['a1','b1','c1','a2','b2','c2','a3','b3','c3','a4','b4','c4','a5','b5','c5'], header = None)
```

Of course the sample cannot be greater than the length of the actual file.
I want to randomly pull lines which exceed the length of lines in the file.
In this case, where "pull > cycle".
Essentially a

```
rand.choice, 'of line in "collections.txt"', N times
```

Is there a way to do this using pd.read_csv?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can always read in the entire dataframe, then take n samples (with replacement, using [rand.choices](https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html#random.choices)) from the row indices and then use iloc to grab the new sampled dataframe.

```
# cycle = 19380816
pull = 10000000

whole_df = pd.read_csv('collection.txt', sep = " ", names = ['a1','b1','c1','a2','b2','c2','a3','b3','c3','a4','b4','c4','a5','b5','c5'], header = None)
i_sample = rand.choices(range(len(whole_df)), k=pull)
new_df = whole_df.iloc[i_sample]
```